# QGraphicsView for 2D RPG

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I would just love to ask a question about the possibly of creating a 2D RPG game in Qt QGraphicsView

A game similar to battle heart - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VqlJ_AvFS8

Why am thinking of using Qt?

- Qt is cross platform, and the support for mobile platforms like iOS and Android is increasing fast
- I want to save the image on HD as SVG
- I want to render the images on the fly ( For the example, when the game is loading ) into pixmap images for better performance after scaling them to the appropriate screen size ( So we cab have a ++, better performance, and infite support to any screen size )

What do you guys think about Qt? Do you have any other good options,

Qt make converting SVG to PNGs as easy as it could be, so that's the killing feature why am sticking to Qt

Bests

Comment: There isn't really much of a question in that question.  Would QGraphicsView work?  Absolutely, as there are a number of games that have been written using it.

Comment: mmmm ... the question may be refrased, can QGraphicsView hold the same amount of Graphic effects as in battleheart game, or as in the video link, and if no, what are the other recommended options

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it would (I've played battleheart).  But most importantly, you should try it.  It's fairly easy to get something up and running quickly in a QGraphicsView so it's probably worth your time to test it.  Especially because I'm pretty positive you'll be happy!  [just use lots of pixmaps and not too many gradients if you're aiming for small devices like androids]

Comment: I already have a game that is total made in QGraphicsView as well, it's called "Dewan of kout lite" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this, and I can confirm that Qt is a perfectly good option, as long as you're not particularly concerned with download size (you're probably going to end up with a minimum of about 30 megs).  You might consider looking into QML for handling your UI animations, as it's particularly well suited for that sort of thing.

I would strongly recommend using the OpenGL 2 backend, as it's fast, and it allows for GLSL shaders, which are good for special effects.  It's also possible to use a QGLWidget as the background so you can do direct opengl drawing if needed.

Edit:  Source is available at https://github.com/lendrick/Orange-Engine/wiki

Comment: I'm setting an OpenGL widget as the viewport for QGraphicsView as am not expert with openGL, then am playing with bunch of QGraphicsPixmapItems all around the screen ( Loaded from SVG files ), basically am doing my custom calculation for skeleton character ( Syncing child position with parent ), anyways thank you, I hope I get more advices

Comment: Also do you have any example I can see of what you've done ( Though no need for source code )

Comment: As it happens, you can look at the source too:  https://github.com/lendrick/Orange-Engine/wiki

Comment: Thank you ;) Even though this is not exactly what am looking at, it's very useful